# How to speed-up data collecting of WEP AP for aircrack?

Tags: wifi, password-cracking, wep, aircrack-ng

I'm using aireplay to collect some data from AP alongside with aircrack.
Unfortunetlly, the proccess seems quite slow to me as I've reached 2000 in more than 20mins so far.
What most affects the speed of data collecting? PWR of AP is -77dB.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use airodump-ng to get the traffic. not aireplay. But that asside you can replay traffic you capture with aireplay as stated here

http://aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=how_to_crack_wep_via_a_wireless_client

if there are no clients available you could use aireplay-ng to fake auth
and then replay the traffic as stated here

http://aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=how_to_crack_wep_with_no_clients

good luck and stay safe

Comment: thank you for your reply, I will try that. I am very new to this matter but since the AP which I am targeting has no or little trafic, could be state steps more effective than ARPs attack through aireplay? How can I stay hide in already penetrated network? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll open a new thread for the issue stumbled above.